# How do I change desktop enviorment in debian

Tags: linux, debian, desktop-environments

I have installed multiple desktop environments when I started debian. I want to change the desktop environment to gnome but I do not know how.

Comment: If it's the same as Ubuntu, you need to install the Gnome desktop environment. Then when you log off, the log-on screen has a drop-down list of desktop environments, which should now include Gnome.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-session-manager
```

Select Gnome, and the following command:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-window-manager
```

then select gnome desktop environment.